# Select after post values not kept

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, spring-form

I have Springform linked to the object (x = modelAttribute). All the fields keep its values after doing POST action. But the (Multi-Select) list (items) , doesn't keep its values.

X Class :

```
class x 
{
    String a;
    String b;

    List<Y> items;
}
```

JSP :

```
<form:form method="post" path="x" modelAttribute="role">
     <form:input path="a" type="text" />
     <form:input path="b" type="text" />
     <form:options items="${mylist}" path="items" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
</form:form>
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/case/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newRole(ModelMap model)
{
    if(!model.containsAttribute("x")){
        model.addAttribute("x", new X());

    }

    return "/roles/newRole";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/case/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doNewCase(@ModelAttribute("x") @Validated X x ,BindingResult bindingResult,ModelMap model)
{       

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        if(!model.containsAttribute("x")){
            model.addAttribute("x", new X());

        }
        return "cases/newCase";
    }



    caseService.addNewCase(x);
    return "cases/list";
}
```

Any suggestion about how to keep values of items Multi-Select after posting ?

Comment: what do you mean after posting ? after posting you can get that in your controller , if you had mapped to the model

Comment: After posting means after submitting the form. It is mapped , all the fields keep the their values without any problem except the Select element. I know that spring form are so smart to handle the posted values without extra coding form us !

Comment: So you can get the values from `select` box in your controller. am i correct with my understanding ?

Comment: Yeah , I can get them in my controller , but I need to set them as selected in the front-end (jsp) page !

Comment: Can you please elaborate it ? after which method , one you are calling to re-direct to the jsp ?

Comment: try http://bitbybitblog.com/forms-and-data-models-in-spring-mvc/ code.

Comment: This one applied for single select element , but on my case it is multiple selection !